# How to use FinancialForce deployment tools?

Tags: deployment

FinancialForce offer a deployment tool at
https://github.com/financialforcedev/df12-deployment-tools

But how can i use that? i can not find any articles about using it, Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you'll find a description:

http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/09/24/deploy-direct-from-github-to-salesforce/

> To include such links in your README file, take the base URL of the
>   following…

```
https://githubsfdeploy.herokuapp.com/app/githubdeploy
```

> Then apply the owner and repository name, e.g.

```
https://githubsfdeploy.herokuapp.com/app/githubdeploy/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi
```

> When visitors to your GitHub repo click such a link, they will be
>   taken through an Salesforce oAuth login flow to their desired org, or
>   if they are already logged in an initial prompt to confirm the app
>   access needs are acceptable.